# How do I say "It matters" and "it doesn't matter"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, phrase

I wonder how do I say "it matters" and "it doesn't matter" so that it sounds more native.

So far, I've found "ça compte" and "cela compte" for "it matters", and "peu importe" and "ça ne fait rien" for "it doesn't matter". But I'm not sure which one is the most regular one which can be used in a conversation with any context

Answer (score 3):

***Cela*** is too formal, probably like using "whom" in a conversation. ***Peu importe*** is slightly formal but nevertheless usable. ***Il importe*** only works if something follows it but is unexpected in a conversation.

Here are common ways to say:

1. It matters.

   - ***C'est important.*** (usual)
   - *Ça a de l'importance.*
   - *Ça compte / On en tient compte.*  (It is taken into account)
2. It doesn't matter.

   - ***C'est pas important.*** (usual)
   - *Ça [n']a pas d'importance.*
   - *Peu importe.*
   - *Ça compte pas.*
   - *On s'en fiche* / *on s'en fout* / *on s'en tape.* (colloquial)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi :

Ça vaut la peine.
Ça vaut le coup.

Et le contraire:

Ça ne vaut pas la peine.
Ça ne vaut pas le coup.

Comment: oui mais ça dépend un peu de contexte (malheureusement pas fourni dans la question)

Answer (score 1):

Correspondingly to English, where the negative is used much more often in phrases, in French, there is a greater number of negative expressions ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+doesn%27t+matter%2Cit+matters&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)). It should be borne in mind that the phrases listed cannot all be used interchangeably in all grammatical contexts; adaptation to the grammar and semantic of a given context may be difficult because not all combinations are idiomatic or because of nuances of meaning.

*It doesn't matter*

- C'est rien. (*a bit informal*)
- Ce n'est rien. (*formal, but not too much*)
- Ça fait rien. (*a bit informal*)
- Ça ne fait rien. (*formal, but not too much*)
- C'est sans intérêt.
- Ça n'a aucune espèce d'importance. (*"It doesn't matter at all"*)
- C'est sans importance.
- C'est sans importance aucune. (*"It doesn't matter at all"*)
- Ça importe peu.
- On n'en a rien à faire.
- C'est sans conséquences.
- Ça n'a pas de conséquences.
  …

*It matters*

- C'est important
- Ça a une importance.
- il y a une différence (*translation of certain cases of "it matters whether", see below*)

> Of course, it matters whether you make a right turn rather than a left.
> *Bien sûr, il y a une différence si vous tournez à droite plutôt qu'à gauche.*
> <s>*Bien sûr, **c'est important** si vous tournez à droite plutôt qu'à gauche.*</s>